# VSC: how to position cursor at specified line in extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to open a Textdocument and jump to a certain line.

Here is what I tried so far:

```js
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(vscode.Uri.file(sctPath)).then(document => {
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(document).then(() => {
        let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor!;
        let range = document.lineAt(20).range;
        editor.revealRange(range);
    })
})
```

The document opens, but the cursor does not goto to line `20`.

The cursor position is just remembered whenever I manually mark a line.

Is there a call missing or something?

Comment: you forget to set the `selection` to the correct position

Comment: @rioVio: thx, that was missing, indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done very easily using the other arguments to `showTextDocument`:

```js
let pos = new vscode.Position(20,0);  // set cursor to start of line 21, it is 0-based

await vscode.window.showTextDocument(
          vscode.Uri.file(sctPath), 
          {selection: new vscode.Range(pos, pos)}
);
```